# Testing Sagas with Jest fails on call, put with major object received differences without a clear explanation

Tags: javascript, jestjs, redux-saga

Pardon the verbose title. I am new to Sagas and wrote a basic Saga which, when a button is clicked, fetches something from an API then puts out some more actions. However, I have been unable to test anything.

My saga:

```js
export function* fetchWorker() {
  yield put({ type: 'BEGIN_LOADING' }); // This is a test put that was added to help diagnose the problem
  try {
    const response = yield call(
      axios.get,
      'http://localhost:<port>/<path>',
    );
    yield put(fetchSucceeded(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchFailed(error));
  }
}

 export function* fetchWatcher() {
   yield takeEvery(types.FETCH_REQUESTED, fetchWorker);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([fetchWatcher()]);
}
```

My test:

```js
describe('Test Saga', () => {
  it('Fetches successfully', () => {
    const gen = fetchWorker();

    expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(put({ type: 'BEGIN_LOADING' }));

    expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(
      call(axios.get, 'http://localhost:<port>/<path>'),
    );

    expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(put(fetchSucceeded(undefined)));
    expect(gen.next('test').value).toEqual(
      put({ type: types.FETCH_SUCCEEDED, data: 'test' }),
    );

    expect(gen.next()).toEqual({ done: true, value: undefined });
  });
```

However, I never get past the first expect. Instead I get this (slightly rearranged to make it more readable:

```bash
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

- Expected
+ Received

  Object {
    "@@redux-saga/IO": true,
-   "combinator": false,
-   "payload": Object {
-     "args": Array [
-       "http://localhost:<port>/<somepath>",
    ],
-     "context": null,
-     "fn": [Function wrap],
-   },
-   "type": "CALL",

+   "combinator": true,
+   "payload": Array [
+     GeneratorFunctionPrototype {
+       "_invoke": [Function invoke],
+     },
+   "type": "ALL",
  }
```

I thought it might be because of how I Used `all()`, so I replaced the root saga with the watcher saga and `takeEvery()` or `takeLatest()`, but they all return the same errors with slightly different text. Where are these objects coming from? Why are they so different from what I am expecting?

I am following instructions on the official docs [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html), as well as elsewhere, especially [this guide](https://medium.com/@ktajpuri/easiest-way-to-test-asynchronous-redux-sagas-with-jest-f47c821393da).

I've also looked elsewhere and I've seen many examples similar to my own. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Best would to write 3 Saga test cases, one for each function.

```
1. rootSaga:
const gen = rootSaga();
expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(all([fetchWatcher()]));
expect(gen.next().done).toBe(true)

2. fetchWatcher:
const gen = fetchWatcher();
expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(takeEvery(types.FETCH_REQUESTED, fetchWorker));
expect(gen.next().done).toBe(true)

3. fetchWorker:
const gen = fetchWorker();
expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(put({ type: 'BEGIN_LOADING' }));
expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(
 call(axios.get, 'http://localhost:<port>/<path>'),
 );
const response = { data: 'dummy data' };
expect(gen.next(response).value).toEqual(put(fetchSucceeded(response.data)));
expect(gen.next().done).toBe(true);
```